# PHP resize image on upload error

Tags: php, upload, image-resizing

i currently have an upload script which saves the image names in a database, however, i want resize the image on upload i currently have this script but it is producing some errors

this is the script:

```
$imagename = $image['name'];

$path = "img/users/$category/$user_id/$imagename";


// *** 1) Initialise / load image
$resizeObj = new resize('$path');

// *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 200, 'crop');

// *** 3) Save image
$resizeObj -> saveImage('$path', 1000);

echo $path;
```

these are the errors:

```
 Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 34

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 35

Warning: Division by zero in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 182

Warning: Division by zero in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 183

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 76

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 77

Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/stude295/public_html/resize-class.php on line 201
img/users/Accessories/admin/IMG_2029.JPG
```

resize-class file:

```
   # ========================================================================#
   #
   #  Author:    Jarrod Oberto
   #  Version:   1.0
   #  Date:      17-Jan-10
   #  Purpose:   Resizes and saves image
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("classes/resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   #
   #
   # ========================================================================#


        Class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

Comment: You better show this `resize-class.php` What is this anyway?

Comment: You need to show the actual resizing code. Given those errors, most likely either the upload failed, or GD was unable to open the image file, returning a boolean false. And given the number of errors, you almost certainly have very little, or most likely utterly NO, error handling to catch such things.

Comment: `resize('$path')` will never work. Look up the difference between single and double quotes (and use simply `resize($path)` in this case). Same for `saveImage('$path', 1000)`...

Comment: ahh thankyou so much! i remember now! sorry still learning, do you know how i would check if a files size (in px) is bigger than a certain size using IF statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$resizeObj = new resize('$path');
```

Instead, try removing the single quotes:

```
$resizeObj = new resize($path);
```

---

> do you know how i would check if a files size (in px) is bigger than a
>   certain size using IF statement?

```
if ($resizeObj->width > 800)
{
    // bigger than 800 pixels in width
}

if ($resizeObj->height > 600)
{
    // bigger than 600 pixels in height
}
```

---

> is there any way i can check IF the images height,width are bigger
>   than say 400px and then carry out the resize if they are

```
$resizeObj = new resize($path);

if (($resizeObj->width > 400) || ($resizeObj->height > 400))
{
    $resizeObj->resizeImage(200, 200, 'crop');
    $resizeObj->saveImage($path, 1000);
}
```

Comment: thankyou! is there any way i can check IF the images height,width are bigger than say 400px and then carry out the resize if they are

Comment: @neeko: And don't use `1000` or even `100` as the image quality, `85`-`90` is more than enough to maintain quality while halving the file size.

Comment: thankyou for all your help but i am getting the error Fatal error: Cannot access private property resize::$width

Comment: @neeko: Didn't noticed that, sorry. Change the `private` keyword on `private $width;` and `private $height;` on the class to `public`, it won't do any harm.

Comment: perfect thankyou so much! i do have another quick question if you dont mind? Someone told me that i shouldn't save user uploaded files in the document root? im not sure what this means and where should i store them instead to be safer?

Comment: @neeko: Yeah, you shouldn't. The most simple scenario to explain why that is dangerous is... Imagine I upload a PHP file (that does some real nasty stuff) instead of a image. At least, you should always validate the mime type and possibly the extension. You should also store them outside of document root (that means the directory where your server looks for `index.php`) or in the database for instance. If you store the files on the disk, you can also chmod it to disallow execution to be on the safe side. But all of this is another question with much to write about, so feel free to ask it. =)